# R ztable latex output not working

Tags: tables, errors, r

I created a table using the `ztable` package in [r](/questions/tagged/r). I cannot get the output to work in `LaTeX` though. I am getting error messages like this;

```
l.74 \definecolor
                 {tempcolor1}{rgb}{0.98,0.41,0.29}
```

I am using this `LaTeX` template - https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-new-hampshire-unh-thesis/njhhrvwvprtp. I do not think this is the issue though, as I tried to compile the code using `RStudio` and that did not work either. Here is the code;

````
\definecolor{tempcolor2}{rgb}{0.79,0.09,0.11} 
\definecolor{tempcolor3}{rgb}{0.98,0.57,0.45} 
\definecolor{tempcolor4}{rgb}{0.93,0.23,0.17} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} 
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{tempcolor5}{rgb}{0.98,0.73,0.63} 
\definecolor{tempcolor6}{rgb}{0.64,0.06,0.08} 
\definecolor{tempcolor7}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.05} 
\definecolor{tempcolor8}{rgb}{0.99,0.88,0.82} 
\definecolor{tempcolor9}{rgb}{1,0.96,0.94} 
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} 
\begin{table}[!hbtp]
\begin{center}
\begin{normalsize}
\color{black}
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
&species&topo (2)&topo (3)&spectral (2)&spectral (3)&topo spectral (2)&topo spectral (3)&soil (2)&soil (3)&all (2)&all (3)\\ 
\hline
1&ABIBAL&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81\\ 
2&ACEPEN&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84\\ 
3&ACERUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68\\ 
4&ACESAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
5&ACESPI&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.48&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
6&ARANUD&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.86&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
7&ARITRI&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.47&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.76&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.80\\ 
8&ATHANG&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
9&BETALL&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.50&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70\\ 
10&CARARC&\cellcolor{yellow}0.55&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78&\cellcolor{yellow}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78\\ 
11&CARINT&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
12&CINLAT&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
13&CLIBOR&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
14&DENPUN&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
15&DRYCAM&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.52&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
16&DRYINT&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
17&FAGGRA&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
18&FRAAME&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
19&HUPLUC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
20&LONCAN&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72\\ 
21&MAICAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79\\ 
22&MAIRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
23&MEDVIR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
24&NABSPP&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
25&OCLACU&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62\\ 
26&OXAMON&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
27&PARNOV&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.62&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.71\\ 
28&PHECON&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
29&PICRUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66\\ 
30&RUBIDA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
31&SAMRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
32&STRAMP&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.57&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
33&TIACOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor9}0.44&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
34&TRIBOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
35&TRIERE&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83\\ 
36&TRIUND&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71\\ 
37&TSUCAN&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.77&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.69&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.79\\ 
38&UVUSES&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
39&VIBLAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
40&VIOBLA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
41&VIOROT&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{normalsize}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\color{black}```

Any ideas?
````

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What exactly does "it does not work" mean? Do you get any error messages or just not the output you wanted to get? Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I added an explanation into my post!

Comment: You should only get an error message complaining about `\definecolor`  from a document that does not load the `xcolor` package. The template you linked to, does in fact load the package. If you used the template as it is and did not do any changed to the preamble, you should end up with an error message such as the following: " Undefined control sequence.
l.64 1&ABIBAL&\cellcolor
{tempcolor1}"  To fix this, add the `table` option to the `xcolor` package (as in `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following MWE should work. I added the `table` option to the `xcolor` package to make the code compilable. Since the table is too large to fit onto the page, I used `makecell` and `rotating` to rotate the table headers and also reduced the font size to `\small`. In order tom improve the code, I made some more changes, that are commented in the code itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % removed hyperref. this package should be the last package in your preamble (with a few exceptions)
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % added table option here, needed for the cellcolor command
\usepackage{makecell,rotating} % added makecell and rotating package, needed for rotated column headers.
\usepackage{setspace}


\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\centering CHAPTER \thechapter}{0pt}{\centering}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % moved hyperref. this package should be the last package in your preamble (with a few exceptions)


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}


\definecolor{tempcolor1}{rgb}{0.98,0.41,0.29}  % added a definition for the color "tempcolor1" since this definition was missing 
\definecolor{tempcolor2}{rgb}{0.79,0.09,0.11} 
\definecolor{tempcolor3}{rgb}{0.98,0.57,0.45} 
\definecolor{tempcolor4}{rgb}{0.93,0.23,0.17} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} 
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{tempcolor5}{rgb}{0.98,0.73,0.63} 
\definecolor{tempcolor6}{rgb}{0.64,0.06,0.08} 
\definecolor{tempcolor7}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.05} 
\definecolor{tempcolor8}{rgb}{0.99,0.88,0.82} 
\definecolor{tempcolor9}{rgb}{1,0.96,0.94} 
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}

\begin{document}

 
\begin{table}[!hbtp]
\small % removed normalsize environment, used small font size instad, otehrwise table would be too large
\centering % replaced the center environment with the centering command since the former adds additional vertical white space which might be undesired
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont spectral} % set width maximum width of rotated text. Longer text is split up into multiple lines.
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
& species & \rothead{topo (2)} & \rothead{topo (3)}&\rothead{spectral (2)}&\rothead{spectral (3)}&\rothead{topo spectral (2)}&\rothead{topo spectral (3)}&\rothead{soil (2)}&\rothead{soil (3)}&\rothead{all (2)}&\rothead{all (3)}\\ 
\hline
1&ABIBAL&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81\\ 
2&ACEPEN&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84\\ 
3&ACERUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68\\ 
4&ACESAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
5&ACESPI&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.48&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
6&ARANUD&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.86&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
7&ARITRI&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.47&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.76&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.80\\ 
8&ATHANG&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
9&BETALL&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.50&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70\\ 
10&CARARC&\cellcolor{yellow}0.55&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78&\cellcolor{yellow}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78\\ 
11&CARINT&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
12&CINLAT&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
13&CLIBOR&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
14&DENPUN&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
15&DRYCAM&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.52&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
16&DRYINT&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
17&FAGGRA&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
18&FRAAME&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
19&HUPLUC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
20&LONCAN&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72\\ 
21&MAICAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79\\ 
22&MAIRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
23&MEDVIR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
24&NABSPP&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
25&OCLACU&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62\\ 
26&OXAMON&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
27&PARNOV&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.62&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.71\\ 
28&PHECON&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
29&PICRUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66\\ 
30&RUBIDA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
31&SAMRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
32&STRAMP&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.57&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
33&TIACOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor9}0.44&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
34&TRIBOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
35&TRIERE&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83\\ 
36&TRIUND&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71\\ 
37&TSUCAN&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.77&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.69&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.79\\ 
38&UVUSES&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
39&VIBLAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
40&VIOBLA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
41&VIOROT&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```