# makecell package error {\let\tabg@pe\theadgape\thead@}

Tags: tables, errors, makecell, stackengine

I have a table that I am trying to use in a Wiley publishing company LaTeX template.

Here is the table I am trying to use - this code thanks to [R ztable latex output not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571480/r-ztable-latex-output-not-working):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in]{geometry}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % removed hyperref. this package should be the last package in your preamble (with a few exceptions)
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % added table option here, needed for the cellcolor command
\usepackage{makecell,rotating} % added makecell and rotating package, needed for rotated column headers.
\usepackage{setspace}


\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\centering CHAPTER \thechapter}{0pt}{\centering}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection}{12pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\normalfont}{\thesubsection}{12pt}{}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} % moved hyperref. this package should be the last package in your preamble (with a few exceptions)


\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{LIST OF REFERENCES}


\definecolor{tempcolor1}{rgb}{0.98,0.41,0.29}  % added a definition for the color "tempcolor1" since this definition was missing 
\definecolor{tempcolor2}{rgb}{0.79,0.09,0.11} 
\definecolor{tempcolor3}{rgb}{0.98,0.57,0.45} 
\definecolor{tempcolor4}{rgb}{0.93,0.23,0.17} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} 
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{tempcolor5}{rgb}{0.98,0.73,0.63} 
\definecolor{tempcolor6}{rgb}{0.64,0.06,0.08} 
\definecolor{tempcolor7}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.05} 
\definecolor{tempcolor8}{rgb}{0.99,0.88,0.82} 
\definecolor{tempcolor9}{rgb}{1,0.96,0.94} 
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}

\begin{document}

 
\begin{table}[!hbtp]
\small % removed normalsize environment, used small font size instad, otehrwise table would be too large
\centering % replaced the center environment with the centering command since the former adds additional vertical white space which might be undesired
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont spectral} % set width maximum width of rotated text. Longer text is split up into multiple lines.
\begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrrrr}
\hline
& species & \rothead{topo (2)} & \rothead{topo (3)}&\rothead{spectral (2)}&\rothead{spectral (3)}&\rothead{topo spectral (2)}&\rothead{topo spectral (3)}&\rothead{soil (2)}&\rothead{soil (3)}&\rothead{all (2)}&\rothead{all (3)}\\ 
\hline
1&ABIBAL&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81\\ 
2&ACEPEN&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84\\ 
3&ACERUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68\\ 
4&ACESAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
5&ACESPI&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.48&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
6&ARANUD&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.86&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
7&ARITRI&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.47&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.76&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.80\\ 
8&ATHANG&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
9&BETALL&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.50&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70\\ 
10&CARARC&\cellcolor{yellow}0.55&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78&\cellcolor{yellow}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78\\ 
11&CARINT&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
12&CINLAT&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
13&CLIBOR&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
14&DENPUN&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
15&DRYCAM&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.52&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
16&DRYINT&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
17&FAGGRA&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
18&FRAAME&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
19&HUPLUC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
20&LONCAN&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72\\ 
21&MAICAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79\\ 
22&MAIRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
23&MEDVIR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
24&NABSPP&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
25&OCLACU&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62\\ 
26&OXAMON&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
27&PARNOV&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.62&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.71\\ 
28&PHECON&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
29&PICRUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66\\ 
30&RUBIDA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
31&SAMRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
32&STRAMP&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.57&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
33&TIACOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor9}0.44&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
34&TRIBOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
35&TRIERE&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83\\ 
36&TRIUND&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71\\ 
37&TSUCAN&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.77&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.69&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.79\\ 
38&UVUSES&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
39&VIBLAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
40&VIOBLA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
41&VIOROT&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it appears that there is an error when I include the `makecell` package into the Wiley template, and the `makecell` package is needed for this table.

Here is a link to download the Wiley template. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HbIrm5Wbo6ruNGhvjOadPs59rNtiM5Gl/view?usp=sharing

If you add `makecell` into the main.tex file on line 74, along with the other required packages, it will result in the following error:

{\let\tabg@pe\theadgape\thead@}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `graphicx` for the rotation via `\rotatebox{<deg>}{<content>}` instead of `makecell`.

`wiley-article` loads a lot of packages and defines a command `\thead` that conflicts with `makecell`.

[image: p]

```
\documentclass{wiley-article}

\geometry{letterpaper,top=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in,left=1in} % needed to change the setup done by the class 

\definecolor{tempcolor1}{rgb}{0.98,0.41,0.29}  % added a definition for the color "tempcolor1" since this definition was missing 
\definecolor{tempcolor2}{rgb}{0.79,0.09,0.11} 
\definecolor{tempcolor3}{rgb}{0.98,0.57,0.45} 
\definecolor{tempcolor4}{rgb}{0.93,0.23,0.17} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5} 
\definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{tempcolor5}{rgb}{0.98,0.73,0.63} 
\definecolor{tempcolor6}{rgb}{0.64,0.06,0.08} 
\definecolor{tempcolor7}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.05} 
\definecolor{tempcolor8}{rgb}{0.99,0.88,0.82} 
\definecolor{tempcolor9}{rgb}{1,0.96,0.94} 
\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0} 
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}

\begin{document}    

\begin{table}[!hbtp]
    \small % removed normalsize environment, used small font size instad, otehrwise table would be too large
    \centering % replaced the center environment with the centering command since the former adds additional vertical white space which might be undesired
%   \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont spectral} % set width maximum width of rotated text. Longer text is split up into multiple lines.
    \begin{tabular}{rlrrrrrrrrrr}
%       \hline
        & species & \rotatebox{90}{topo (2)} & \rotatebox{90}{topo (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{spectral (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{spectral (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{topo spectral (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{topo spectral (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{soil (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{soil (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{all (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{all (3)}\\ 
        \hline
        1&ABIBAL&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81\\ 
        2&ACEPEN&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84\\ 
        3&ACERUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68\\ 
        4&ACESAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
        5&ACESPI&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.48&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
        6&ARANUD&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.86&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
        7&ARITRI&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{yellow}0.47&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.76&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.80\\ 
        8&ATHANG&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
        9&BETALL&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.50&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70\\ 
        10&CARARC&\cellcolor{yellow}0.55&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78&\cellcolor{yellow}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.78\\ 
        11&CARINT&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
        12&CINLAT&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
        13&CLIBOR&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
        14&DENPUN&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
        15&DRYCAM&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.52&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
        16&DRYINT&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.61&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{yellow}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
        17&FAGGRA&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.84&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.82\\ 
        18&FRAAME&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
        19&HUPLUC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
        20&LONCAN&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.58&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72\\ 
        21&MAICAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.81&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79\\ 
        22&MAIRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78\\ 
        23&MEDVIR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76\\ 
        24&NABSPP&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.63&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
        25&OCLACU&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62\\ 
        26&OXAMON&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.56&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
        27&PARNOV&\cellcolor{yellow}0.63&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.62&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.65&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.59&\cellcolor{yellow}0.71\\ 
        28&PHECON&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
        29&PICRUB&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66\\ 
        30&RUBIDA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.61&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69\\ 
        31&SAMRAC&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor8}0.49&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.51&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.78&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
        32&STRAMP&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.56&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.53&\cellcolor{yellow}0.57&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.54&\cellcolor{yellow}0.66\\ 
        33&TIACOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.52&\cellcolor{tempcolor9}0.44&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.77\\ 
        34&TRIBOR&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73\\ 
        35&TRIERE&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor7}\color{white}0.83\\ 
        36&TRIUND&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.62&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71\\ 
        37&TSUCAN&\cellcolor{yellow}0.67&\cellcolor{yellow}0.77&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{yellow}0.69&\cellcolor{yellow}0.72&\cellcolor{yellow}0.60&\cellcolor{yellow}0.68&\cellcolor{yellow}0.70&\cellcolor{yellow}0.79\\ 
        38&UVUSES&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.53&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.57&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.58&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.66&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.75\\ 
        39&VIBLAN&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.71&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.67&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.70&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.83\\ 
        40&VIOBLA&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{gray}\color{gray}0.42&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.64&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor3}0.59&\cellcolor{tempcolor1}\color{white}0.65&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.68&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74\\ 
        41&VIOROT&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.69&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.73&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor5}0.55&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.79&\cellcolor{tempcolor4}\color{white}0.72&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.74&\cellcolor{tempcolor2}\color{white}0.76&\cellcolor{tempcolor6}\color{white}0.80\\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is a list of packages loaded by `wiley-article`. Some of the settings used and the fonts depend on whether `pdflatex` or `xelatex \ lualatex` is detected.

```
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{mathtools}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\RequirePackage{dashrule}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{authblk}
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\RequirePackage{soul}
\RequirePackage{xpatch}
\RequirePackage{afterpage}
\RequirePackage[switch]{lineno}
\RequirePackage{lineno}
\RequirePackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{silence}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} %pdflatex
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} %pdflatex
\RequirePackage{tgtermes}
\RequirePackage{lato}
\RequirePackage{stix}   
\RequirePackage[cmintegrals,nosymbolsc]{newtxsf}
\RequirePackage[paperwidth=171mm,paperheight=246mm, left=14.3mm,textwidth=142.4mm,lines=47, headsep=\baselineskip,headheight=16\p@, footskip=23\p@,columnsep=2em]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{alphalph}
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage[flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{changepage}
\RequirePackage{environ}
\RequirePackage{marginnote}
\RequirePackage{quoting}
\RequirePackage[inline]{enumitem}
\RequirePackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\RequirePackage{threeparttable}
\RequirePackage{stfloats}
\RequirePackage{newfloat}
\RequirePackage{enotez}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{amsrefs}
\RequirePackage{lettrine}
```

**UPDATE**
To add line breaks in the headers in order to reduce vertical space, you can use the package `stackengine`.

(1) Add this lines to your preamble

```
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newcommand{\mri}[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\Centerstack[l]{#1}}}
```

(2) Start the tabular with

```
\begin{tabular}{rl ccc ccc ccc c}  %  centering all columns
    & species & \rotatebox{90}{topo (2)} & \rotatebox{90}{topo (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{spectral (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{spectral (3)}&\mri{topo \\spectral \\(2)}&\mri{topo \\spectral\\ (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{soil (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{soil (3)}&\rotatebox{90}{all (2)}&\rotatebox{90}{all (3)}\\ 
    \hline

....
```

e.g. replace`\rotatebox{90}{topo \\ spectral (2)}` with `\mri{topo \\ spectral \\(2)}`,  etc.

[image: x]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the solution and explanation. Is it possible to put line breaks in the column headers so that the table header does not take up so much vertical space, similar to what is shown in the example table that I provided?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.