# How to correct !Undefined control sequence error created by \definecolor?

Tags: pdftex, color, r

I'm trying to create a pdf table generated in latex format in R, but any of the commands below generates and !Undefined control sequence error. I tried removing this line or putting it below the \begin{table}[!hbtp] line, but the error keeps on appearing. How to solve this issue? The code to reproduce this problem is below:

```
#R
library(ztable)
library(tinytex)
library(tools)
library(latexpdf)

options(ztable.type="latex") #or latex for latex output.

z <- ztable(head(iris),caption="Table 1. Basic Table")
cat(capture.output(z), sep = "\n", file = "tablez.tex")

texi2pdf("tablez.tex")
latexmk("tablez.tex")
tex2pdf("tablez.tex")
```

The previous code fails with the following error:

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,  : 
  Running 'texi2dvi' on 'tablez.tex' failed.
LaTeX errors:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \definecolor
                {black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
?
```

Running pdflatex in the command line produces the same error

```
#zsh
> pdflatex tablez.tex 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/MacPorts 2022.62882_2) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tablez.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-02-24>
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \definecolor
                {black}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
?
```

Comment: you need `color` or `xcolor` package

Comment: Somewhat duplicate of [R ztable latex output not working](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/571480/106162).  This is likely a bug in the R `ztable` package though.